# Use Vue phone number component outside of Vue app

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components

I have a static website that I would like to add a Vue component to. I cannot get it to recognize the component that I'm trying to add. It's called `vue-phone-number-input` https://github.com/LouisMazel/vue-phone-number-input It says `VuePhoneNumberInput is not defined`. Here's what I have:

```
<script src="../../assets/global/js/vue/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../assets/global/js/vue/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../assets/global/js/vue/vue-phone-number-input.umd.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/global/css/vue-phone-number-input.css">

<div id="phone-search">
   <VuePhoneNumberInput class="search-input" v-model="phoneNumber" :only-countries="['US']" @update="onUpdate" />
</div>

new Vue({
      el: '#phone-search',
      components: {
          VuePhoneNumberInput: VuePhoneNumberInput
      },
      data: {
         phoneNumber: null
      }
})
```

I have tried `VuePhoneNumberInput: 'vue-phone-number-input'` and the error goes away but the component still does not render. I have tried adding `Vue.component('vue-phone-number-input', window.VuePhoneNumberInput.default);` as is in the docs but I get the error `Cannot read property 'default' of undefined`. I have also tried the other Vue script they have in the doc, `unpkg.com/vue` which doesn't work either. Vue itself is working properly within the #phone-search element, it is just the component that's not working.

Comment: How do you import `VuePhoneNumberInput` into the Vue context? Can you share your `main.js` files that contains all your component imports?

Comment: I do not know how it's supposed to be imported. On a different page I have used a different Vue component and all that was required was adding the script to the page and components: {VPaginator: VuePaginator}. I don't know why this one's different. I cannot use 'import'.

Comment: I just tried out both UMD and the usual ES6 import method - UMD doesn't work, while ES6 does. I'd say to follow @Hamed Baatour's solution, if that is possible for you.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the library UMD bundle is broken so avoid using it and import the library using ES6 imports.

here is a working example: [Live Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-wea7yk?file=index.js)